# triggering segues from inside function with parameters

Tags: ios

I have the following code and I am trying to trigger a segue transition if condition of if-statement is valid. I would also like to pass 3 variables values (fullname, year, country) along to next view. The below action is triggered when button is clicked. Please advice on how to do this:

```
-(IBAction)checkInputAndProceed:(id)sender{
    NSString *fullname = [self.fullnameTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSString *year = [self.yearTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    NSString *country = [self.countriesTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    if(fullname.length == 0) {
      self.fullnameError.text = @"Please fill your name";
    }else{
      self.fullnameError.text = @"";
    }

    if(year.length == 0) {
      self.yearError.text = @"Please fill your birth year";
    }else{
        self.yearError.text = @"";
    }

    if(country.length == 0) {
     self.countryError.text = @"Please select your country";
    }else{
        self.countryError.text = @"";
    }

    if((country.length != 0 && year.length != 0 && fullname.length != 0))
    {
        //Proceed to next view with data stored transferred via segue.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`:

`NSArray` sample:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToNextVC" sender:@[[country text], [year text], [fullname text]]];
```

In `prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoToNextVC"])
{
    NSArray *data = (NSArray *)sender;
    NSString *country = [data objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *year = [data objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *fullName = [data objectAtIndex:2];
}
```

`NSDictionary` sample:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToNextVC" sender:@{@"Country":[country text], @"Year":[year text], @"FullName":[fullname text]}];
```

In `prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoToNextVC"])
{
    NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *)sender;
    NSString *country = [data objectForKey:@"Country"];
    NSString *year = [data objectForKey:@"Year"];
    NSString *fullName = [data objectForKey:@"FullName"];
}
```

But since you already did the check (length after trimming) in your test, why not directly in `prepareForSegue:sender:` do

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoToNextVC"])
{
    NSString *country = [self.countriesTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *year = [self.yearTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSString *fullName = [self.fullnameTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
}
```

Comment: Larme if I do the above, I will have to do it in a separate method prepareForSegue but I would like to perform the transition after validating in the above function.

Comment: I didn't get your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do away with the `IBAction` method and just trigger the segue directly from your button in the Storyboard.

You then need to implement two methods `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` and `prepareForSegueWithIdentifier`.  The first is used to validate your data, the second to pass the data to the next VC.  You can't do it in a single method.

Assuming your segue identifier is 'nextSegue' then you would have something like -

```
    - (BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {

       BOOL ret=YES;

       if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"nextSegue"]) {

          self.fullnameTextfield.text = [self.fullnameTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

          self.yearTextfield.text = [self.yearTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

          self.countriesTextfield.text = [self.countriesTextfield.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

         if (self.fullnameTextfield.text.length == 0) {
            self.fullnameError.text = @"Please fill your name";
            ret=NO;
         } else{
            self.fullnameError.text = @"";
         }

         if (self.yearTextfield.text.length == 0) {
            self.yearError.text = @"Please fill your birth year";
            ret=NO;
         } else{
            self.yearError.text = @"";

         if(self.countriesTextfield.text.length == 0) {
            self.countryError.text = @"Please select your country";
            ret=NO;
         } else{
           self.countryError.text = @"";
         }
      }

       return ret;
    }

    -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

       if ([segue.identifer isEqualToString:@"nextSegue"]) {
           MyNextVC *nextVC=(MyNextVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
           nextVC.fullname=self.fullnameTextfield.text;
           nextVC.year=self.yearTextField.text;
           nextVC.country=self.countriesTextField.text;
       }
    }
```